# Where can I find a specification for Hypertext Inter-ORB Protocol (HTIOP)?

Tags: http, networking, protocols, corba, iiop

According to wikipedia, HTIOP is an implementation of IIOP over HTTP.  IIOP being an specific instance of CORBA's GIOP (general inter-ORB protocol) over TCP/IP.

However, I cannot find a specification for this protocol anywhere on the web!

Answer (score 3):

HTIOP is a TAO specific prototol, see http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu for obtaining a copy of TAO